# Access violation error in NASM, when try to write into .myText segment in windows 8

Tags: windows, nasm, shellcode

when i try following shellcode program to pop up message box in my windows 32 bit system using NASM i get error.

```
section .myText progbits alloc exec write align=16
    global  _WinMain@16
_WinMain@16:
    xor eax, eax
    xor ebx, ebx
    xor ecx, ecx
    xor edx, edx

    jmp short GetLibrary
LibraryReturn:
    pop ecx
    mov BYTE [ecx+10], dl
    mov ebx, 0x76d62fe4
    push ecx
    call ebx

    jmp short FunctionName

FunctionReturn:
    pop ecx
    xor edx, edx
    mov BYTE [ecx+11], dl
    push ecx        
    push eax        ; handle to the module user32.dll
    mov ebx, 0x76d616b9    ; GetProcAddress
    call ebx
        ; now eax has the procAddress of 'MessageBoxA'
    jmp short Message

MessageReturn:    

    pop ecx
    xor edx, edx
    mov BYTE [ecx+16] , dl
    push edx
    push ecx
    push ecx 
    push edx
    call eax        ;MessageBoxA(windowhandle,msg,title,type)

ender:
    xor edx,edx
    push eax            
    mov eax, 0x76d63176        ;exitprocess(exitcode);
    call eax

Message:
    call MessageReturn
    db 'hello am melvin!'

FunctionName:
    call FunctionReturn
    db 'MessageBoxAN'    

GetLibrary:
    call LibraryReturn
    db 'user32.dllN'
```

i compiled

```
C:\SHELL>nasm -f win32 -o msgbox.o msgbox.asm

C:\SHELL>ld -o msgbox.exe msgbox.o
```

it doesn't show any error, but when i run this, 
"i get windows Debug window- with a message: 'messagebox.exe' has stopped working' "

What is the problem in my code. how can i execute a NASM code in windows without error.?

**Now i disabled ASLR. And i found this is the problem.

*Unhandled exception at 0x00404003 in Sample.exe: 0xC0000005: Access 
violation writing location 0x00404019.*
`00404003 C6 41 05 00          mov         byte ptr [ecx+10],0`

so how can i get rid of AV. i edited bcdedit.exe. but doesn't work**

in linux when i try this,

```
section .myText progbits alloc exec write align=16
```

it was working but in windows, doesn't.

Comment: Try using a debugger. Also, this is a ridiculously complicated way of displaying a message. Just call MessageBox directly.

Comment: which debugger do i will use? is the problem because of ASLR? but i wrote a program with LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to get the address of functions in kernel32.dll. it always gives me same address for a function.

Comment: Now i disabled ASLR. And i found this is the problem.       Unhandled exception at 0x00404003 in Sample.exe: 0xC0000005: Access 

violation writing location 0x00404019.

00404003 C6 41 05 00          mov         byte ptr [ecx+5],0      so how can i get rid of AV. i edited bcdedit.exe. but doesn't work

Comment: Just call `MessageBox` like this: `lea ecx, message`, `push 0`, `push ecx`, `push ecx`, `push 0`, `call [__imp__MessageBoxA@16]`. There's no reason to be doing it in such a complicated manner.

Comment: i just need to know how to write shellcode, so am trying this manner. So can you please explain how can i overcome the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i myself find out the answer.....:yeye::yeye::yeye::

we have to change only ,

the "section"

```
section .myText progbits alloc exec write align=16
```

and compile it using "elf32" instead of "win32"

```
nasm -f elf32 -o MessageBox.o MessageBox.asm
gcc -o MessageBox.exe MessageBox.o
```

thats it ,,it would work fine....:blackhat: 
and don't forget to disable  ASLR

note: elf allows you to specify additional information on the SECTION directive line, to control the type and properties of sections you declare.